# Javascript: return функции из промиса

Tags: javascript, функции, promise

Есть такая штука:

```
this.friends = Object.keys(obj).map(x => {

  this.$http.get('http://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/'+obj[x].email+'?alt=json')
    .then(response => {
      return response.body; //это нужно вернуть
    }, response => {
      console.log(response);
    });

});
```

Вопрос в том, как вернуть в map функцию из then в промисе?

**UPD:** Ответы [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%98%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6) не помогли. Единственное, что могло бы помочь оттуда - это генератор. Но он в map функции не работает ([тут прочтал](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316765/why-is-es6-yield-a-reserved-word-when-called-in-this-context) и сам проверил)

Comment: почитаю. Не удаляйте только пока эту тему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть у `Promise` метод `all()`, который возвращает результат выполнения всех промисов в виде массива, соответственно в твоем случае нужно составить массив этих промисов.

```
const arrayOfPromises = Object.keys(obj).map(x => {
  return this.$http.get('http://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/'+obj[x].email+'?alt=json')
    .then(response => response.body);
});
```

Затем ты юзаешь

```
Promise.all(arrayOfPromises).then(result => {
  this.friends = result;
})
```

Где `result` это массив всех ответов.

Comment: Спасибо, вроде работает

Comment: Ну вот зачем один промиз оборачивать в другой через конструктор? Метод `then` **уже** возвращает промиз, его не надо дополнительно "промизифицировать".